# Throw Exception after add aop config

Tags: spring, aop, noclassdeffounderror, spring-aop, beancreationexception

At first, I have a spring application works fine:

[image]

but when to add aop config to aop.xml like this,  It throws a very lang exception.
[image]

this is AOP.java:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.animal.Cat;

public class AOP {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.println("1");
        BeanFactory factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("aop.xml");
        Cat c1 =(Cat)factory.getBean("cat1");
        System.out.println("2");
        c1.mark();

    }
}
```

this is Cat.java:

```
package com.animal;
public class Cat {
    public void mark(){
        System.out.println("cat is mark");
    }
}
```

this is Rat.java:

```
package com.animal;

public class Rat {
    public void sleep(){
        System.out.println("rat is sleep");
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("rat running");
    }
}
```

this is xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
">


<bean id="cat1" class="com.animal.Cat">
</bean>

<bean id="rat1" class="com.animal.Rat">
</bean>

<aop:config>

    <aop:pointcut id="cat_mark" expression="execution(public void com.animal.Cat.mark())"  />

    <aop:aspect ref="rat1">
        <aop:before method="sleep" pointcut-ref="cat_mark" />
        <aop:after method="run" pointcut-ref="cat_mark" />
    </aop:aspect>

</aop:config>
```

As you can see, this is a very simple application, I just want to use spring AOP to make rat do some action before cat going to mark.

I have config XML file which copies from some tutorial, but I can not find what is wrong with it.

---

yeah, I miss `aspectjweaver.jar` which `org.springframework.context` required.
This is the solution:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the implementation of `Animal.Cat`?

Comment: @Gaurav it is my problem, re-edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have edited your question, so I am editing my answer because now I can reproduce your problem.

Actually your original pointcut was correct. Forget what I said about it being wrong, I parsed it wrong when I first saw it. Just change it back to using only a single `*`, please:

```java
execution(* com.animal.Cat.mark(..))
```

Now I think your problem is far simpler, judging from the callstack you posted earlier but cut off in order to replace it by a screenshot of an incomplete callstack. But I found it in your question's history, looking at the old version:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
```

I believe you just forgot to put `aspectjweaver.jar` (or a versioned name like `aspectjweaver-1.8.13`) on the classpath when running the application. Do that and it should go away. If I do that, your application prints:

```
1
Apr 20, 2018 6:04:34 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFORMATION: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@18769467: startup date [Fri Apr 20 18:04:34 ICT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 20, 2018 6:04:35 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFORMATION: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [aop.xml]
2
rat is sleep
cat is mark
rat running
```

Comment: thanks, I re-edit the question. I have some experience with JavaScript and Python, but I don't know Java is so different whit them.

Comment: It was not a good idea to remove the XML and replace it by a screenshot. Nobody can Copy & paste your code from a screenshot in order to reproduce your problem. Screenshots are nice as additional information, not as replacements of actual code. I am going to look into it, though.

Comment: I updated my answer in order to present the solution for your problem.